# Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Method and child routes

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

i have defined two routes, /shoppingcart/ and  a child route /shoppingcart/add/ which should only be available for POST requests.

```
        'routes' => array(
        'shoppingcart' => array(
            'type'    => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'       => '/shoppingcart/',
                'defaults'    => array(
                    'controller' => 'ShoppingcartController',
                    'action'     => 'shoppingcart',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array (
                'add-product' => array(
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => array(
                        'verb' => 'post',
                        'route' => 'add/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'ShoppingcartController',
                            'action' => 'addProductToShoppingcart',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ),
    )
```

The route /shoppingcart/ works fine. The child route /shoppingcart/add/ does not work(404 error with POST and GET).

When i change the type from method to literal and remove the verb key it works.

How can i use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Method in the child route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `may_terminate` true for your child route.

Also, you mention route failing for GET, which it will if you only set the verb to `post`, if you want to allow `get` too, the verb should be `get,post`

Edit: after a little experimenting, it turns out my understanding was wrong, the `Method` type needs to be placed as parent of the route it's protecting....

```
'routes' => array(
    'shoppingcart' => array(
        'type'    => 'literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'       => '/shoppingcart/',
            'defaults'    => array(
                'controller' => 'ShoppingcartController',
                'action'     => 'shoppingcart',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array (
            'add-product' => array(
                'type' => 'method',
                'options' => array(
                    'verb' => 'get,post',
                ),
                'child_routes' => array(
                    // actual route is a child of the method
                    'form' => array(
                        'may_terminate' => true,
                        'type' => 'literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => 'add/',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'ShoppingcartController',
                                'action' => 'addProductToShoppingcart',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I first thought this would fix it, but my type was set to literal. It still has the same behavior it works with type=literal but not with type=method.

Comment: @Crisp can you explain me how to use this route in view. I don't know more about method routing in zf2.