# zend framework 2 segment route with child method routes

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to configure segment route with child method routes. But got an exception message "Missing parameter "id"". Can't find what's wrong. Help please.

```php
'admin-pages-edit' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/admin/pages/edit/:id',
            'constraints' => array(
                'id' => '[1-9][0-9]*',
            ),
        ),
        'child_routes' => array(
            'admin-pages-edit-get' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Method',
                'options' => array(
                    'verb' => 'get',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Module\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'AdminPages',
                        'action'        => 'editGet',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'admin-pages-edit-post' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Method',
                'options' => array(
                    'verb' => 'post',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Module\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'AdminPages',
                        'action'        => 'editPost',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Did you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555040/3283363

Comment: see please answer below